# CSVs: how to output missing data to make processing easier?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, csv, excel

If supplying data (that can be either string or numeric) via CSVs, what's a good strategy for marking that a value is missing?

- Some non-empty sentinel, like `NA`
- Some non-empty sentinel, but quoted like `"NA"`
- The empty string, e.g. in the CSV the value will be 0 characters long.
- The quoted empty string `""`
- Something else / depending on case?

If it makes a difference, would like the CSVs to behave reasonably when read using R readr, Python Pandas, and Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both pandas and readr allow flexibility on the marker used to indicate missing values, allowing to specify values that should be treated as missing when reading csvs:

- readr https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html
- pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

given that, maybe you can handle missing data in your code rather than replacing values in the original csvs.

If you get to choose, maybe `NA` (no hyphens) is a sensible default as it's handled as missing value by both libs by default.

Comment: I realise `NA` is the ISO country code of Namibia, and I am likely to be outputting country codes...

Comment: OK, maybe you have a case to override the default NA values (in pandas, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952142/prevent-pandas-from-interpreting-na-as-nan-in-a-string) and indeed use another symbol to avoid that conflict.